# Is there a free .NET library for Word documents?

Tags: .net, ms-word

I've found a nice free [library for operating on Excell workbooks](http://code.google.com/p/excellibrary/) for C#. Does anyone know is there a **FREE** library to do the same with the Word files ?

Comment: Why not just use COM interop?

Comment: danyolgiax >> it doesn't matter in my case

Answer (score 4):

You can try [OpenXML SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=5124)